# Click Function on jQuery plugin only allows for single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've created this simple plugin to add multiple animations on click but the problem is that once the object is clicked it can not repeat the animation by clicking again, i can't figure out why the added class is not removing itself after the click function is complete to allow it to be clicked again and repeat.. any suggestions?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.vivify = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            animation: 'bounce',
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var o = options;
            var obj = $(this);
            var animation = o.animation;
            obj.bind("click", function() {
                obj.addClass(o.animation);
                obj.addClass('vivify');
            }, function() {
                obj.removeClass(o.animation);
            });
        })
    }
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: when do you want to remove class, after animation end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example (I guess, because I don't know exactly what's the intended effect of your plugin):

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Fmr9g/

Comment: yours worked perfectly, but i then edited it to apply my animations and no luck.. here's the updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Fmr9g/1/ any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is related to CSS now, not to jQuery. In fact, if you inspect the DOM, you'll see the CSS classes changing as expected.

Comment: Here's another working example with CSS3 animations: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Fmr9g/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.bind("click", function() {
        obj.addClass(o.animation);
        obj.addClass('vivify');
}, 
// this callback is not valid
function() {
     obj.removeClass(o.animation);
 });
```

because `.bind()` accept parameters like following:

```
.bind(eventName, [eventData], [callback])
```

Read about [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind)

To remove class you can do:

```
obj.bind("click", function() {
    obj.addClass(o.animation);
    obj.addClass('vivify');
    // you can removeClass here
    obj.removeClass(o.animation);

   // but you need some delay

   setTimeou(function() {
      obj.removeClass(o.animation);
   }, 5000);
});
```

To increase the timeout you can do following:

```
return this.each(function(index, val) {
       var o = options;
       var obj = $(this);
       var animation = o.animation;
       obj.bind("click", function() {
         obj.addClass(o.animation);
         obj.addClass('vivify');
       }, index * 2000);
});
```

Comment: thank you! i tried the suggested method but it does not work, still only fires with a single click

Comment: let me know if you have any suggestions, i really appreciate the help!

Comment: @user1427307 don't catch the problem, but you `click` is working just fine, if you see `console.log(obj.attr('class'))`, then you'll see class name is toggling just fine, I think issue is with `CSS`.

Comment: thanks i see that too, i can get it work just fine with the toggleClass but the annoying part is you have to click the image once to activate the animation then click it again to disable it and then click it again to activate it again, i'm trying to just single click activate it then remove it as soon as it's done